# Difference between software occupation and hardware occupation on a serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to detect if there is any device connected to a serial port or not! When I open a serial port there is no exception even though there is no device physically attached to the port. My guess is that the port might be occupied by a software, but how can I detect it?

Comment: Is it a known device? Do you know communication parameters: bauds, parity, stop bits?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don´t need anything to be "phisically" connected to the serial port to open it. Whenever you plug something that is sending data in the same parameters you openened it, then you will start receiving data.

You can actually test this behavior using Hyperterminal or some serial communication software. It will work the same.

Via WMI, you can query to know if a specific hardware is connected:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher manObjSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_SerialPort");
ManagementObjectCollection manObjReturn = manObjSearch.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject manObj in manObjReturn)
{
    Console.WriteLine(manObj["DeviceID"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(manObj["Name"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(manObj["Caption"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: I've already known what you say.but I need to detect that port is occupied by my device or a software

Comment: is your port physical or virtual?

Comment: It's Physical and I'd like to content it to Com1. But in both situation contented or disconnected opening port is accorded without exception

Comment: If it is physical and you can connect then any application can be writing to it. If you can´t connect there cannot be any application writing to it since it is physical and not virtual there has to be a physical hardware connected to it. The only way it will fire an exception is if you want to open the port and something(physycal) is connnected